# Jetpack Compose Spacer with background color not shown on screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a card with this design

[image: Design]

Here is the code I am trying to do it.

```
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, 
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Cyan)
) {
    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 16.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(16.dp)
    )

    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround) {
        Text(text = "Title")
        Text(
            text = text
        )
    }
}
```

The preview shows exactly what I want to do. But the spacer is not shown on the screen

Comment: Works fine by me.  What version of Compose are you using?

Comment: it works fine in my case

Comment: Can you see the spacer in the view hierarchy when using the Layout Inspector?

Comment: I use 1.0.5 composse version. 

Do you see the white spacer on the row in the emulator or real device? I have it on the preview, but when debugging on a real device it is not(

Comment: When i try use Layout Inspector, app is being killed... And when i use Inspector with emulator, i don't see actual information, it shows the home screen layout only

Answer (score 10):

Try adding background at the last.

```
Spacer(
       modifier = Modifier
                .height(8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)
        )
```